# Ocultando chave de descriptografia AES em app android

Tags: c#, android, criptografia, compilação, aes

Como posso não só ocultar as chaves AES mas também criptografar e descriptografar usando as chaves/comandos predefinidos em uma biblioteca nativa(*encode.so*), de modo que eu possa compilar e incluí-la em minha aplicação android.

Ou seja, chamando as funções nativas na biblioteca para a obtenção das operações `encrypt(String text)` e `decrypt(String text)`.

Atualmente utilizo o código abaixo.

```
public class encode {

    private String iv = "00000000000000iv"; //Dummy iv
    private String SecretKey = "0000000secretkey"; //Dummy secretKey

    private IvParameterSpec ivspec;
    private SecretKeySpec keyspec;
    private Cipher cipher;


    public encode()
    {
        ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv.getBytes());
        keyspec = new SecretKeySpec(SecretKey.getBytes(), "AES");

        try {
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public byte[] encrypt(String text) throws Exception
    {
        if(text == null || text.length() == 0) {
            throw new Exception("Empty string");
        }
        byte[] encrypted = null;
        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyspec, ivspec);
            encrypted = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception("[encrypt] " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return encrypted;
    }

    public byte[] decrypt(String code) throws Exception
    {
        if(code == null || code.length() == 0) {
            throw new Exception("Empty string");
        }
        byte[] decrypted = null;
        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keyspec, ivspec);
            decrypted = cipher.doFinal(hexToBytes(code));
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception("[decrypt] " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return decrypted;
    }

    public static String bytesToHex(byte[] data)
    {
        if (data==null) {
            return null;
        }
        int len = data.length;
        String str = "";
        for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
            if ((data[i]&0xFF)<16) {
                str = str + "0" + java.lang.Integer.toHexString(data[i]&0xFF);
            }
            else {
                str = str + java.lang.Integer.toHexString(data[i]&0xFF);
            }
        }
        return str;
    }

    public static byte[] hexToBytes(String str) {
        if (str==null) {
            return null;
        }
        else if (str.length() < 2) {
            return null;
        }
        else {
            int len = str.length() / 2;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[len];
            for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
                buffer[i] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(str.substring(i*2,i*2+2),16);
            }
            return buffer;
        }
    }

}
```

- Como eu poderia fazer uma versão compilada da função acima?

---

Exemplo da [web](https://gist.github.com/bricef/2436364) de criptografia AES em C, quem sabe ajuda a ter uma ideia da operação desejada, porem não sei como chamar essa função(*de forma nativa*) ou se ela precisa de ajustes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/*
 * MCrypt API available online:
 * http://linux.die.net/man/3/mcrypt
 */
#include <mcrypt.h>

#include <math.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int encrypt(
    void* buffer,
    int buffer_len, /* Because the plaintext could include null bytes*/
    char* IV, 
    char* key,
    int key_len 
){
  MCRYPT td = mcrypt_module_open("rijndael-128", NULL, "cbc", NULL);
  int blocksize = mcrypt_enc_get_block_size(td);
  if( buffer_len % blocksize != 0 ){return 1;}

  mcrypt_generic_init(td, key, key_len, IV);
  mcrypt_generic(td, buffer, buffer_len);
  mcrypt_generic_deinit (td);
  mcrypt_module_close(td);

  return 0;
}

int decrypt(
    void* buffer,
    int buffer_len,
    char* IV, 
    char* key,
    int key_len 
){
  MCRYPT td = mcrypt_module_open("rijndael-128", NULL, "cbc", NULL);
  int blocksize = mcrypt_enc_get_block_size(td);
  if( buffer_len % blocksize != 0 ){return 1;}

  mcrypt_generic_init(td, key, key_len, IV);
  mdecrypt_generic(td, buffer, buffer_len);
  mcrypt_generic_deinit (td);
  mcrypt_module_close(td);

  return 0;
}

void display(char* ciphertext, int len){
  int v;
  for (v=0; v<len; v++){
    printf("%d ", ciphertext[v]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
  MCRYPT td, td2;
  char * plaintext = "test text 123";
  char* IV = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA";
  char *key = "0123456789abcdef";
  int keysize = 16; /* 128 bits */
  char* buffer;
  int buffer_len = 16;

  buffer = calloc(1, buffer_len);
  strncpy(buffer, plaintext, buffer_len);

  printf("==C==\n");
  printf("plain:   %s\n", plaintext);
  encrypt(buffer, buffer_len, IV, key, keysize); 
  printf("cipher:  "); display(buffer , buffer_len);
  decrypt(buffer, buffer_len, IV, key, keysize);
  printf("decrypt: %s\n", buffer);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Quem são os pares da comunicação? De fato, o lugar correto para chaves é num arquivo de configuração, não nos fontes, e o IV é escolhido aleatoriamente pra cifrar e guardado junto com a cifra para poder decifrar. O problema maior é como colocar essa chave lá... O app poderia gerá-la automaticamente durante a instalação, mas aí tudo que for cifrado por ele só poderá ser decifrado por ele próprio. É isso que você quer? Porque se não for, você precisaria de um meio de compartilhar a chave entre o app e o outro par da comunicação, e isso pode ser bem difícil na prática. Qual é seu objetivo?

Comment: O app recebe os dados encriptados, junto com o IV, que pode ser mudado de tempos em tempos no servidor. O app apenas tem uma das duas keys necessárias para a decodificação, que também é codificada com aes mas ficam no próprio app. Os dados de saída não são encriptados pois não tem o mesmo grau de informações sensíveis que entram, alem disse, todo o trafego está sobre a criptografia SSL. Ciei uma função customizada para embaralhar e misturar todas as informações e keys criptografadas.

Comment: Esse exemplo também serviria para que eu tomasse como base e incluísse mais dados não sensíveis na library. Só queria armazenar a função de descriptografia fora do app, e que também fosse possível usar uma key externa a já inclusa na library. Meu app é hibrido, todas as páginas são remotas, ou seja, via webview, o que realmente é passado é os dados de suma importância, a parte não hibrida e que processa e executa/exibe as informações ao usuário. @mgibsonbr Espero que tenha compreendido melhor.

Answer (score 0):

Ótima questão e a solução é mais simples do que parece. 
Em muitos exemplos que você encontrar na Internet, os IVs e as chaves estão em constantes. Isso é um problema como você observou e, se mesmo assim você ofuscar o código, estará disponível.

Uma solução efetiva para isso é obter a chave, variar o iv a cada operação de rede.

Ou, caso seu software não tenha interação com a Web, fazer a obtenção dessa chave faça isso na sua ferramenta de build, maven, gradle etc.